# How to remove focus of all Edit-text by clicking a button?

Tags: android

How can I change focus from Edit-text to Button by clicking a button? Or remove all the focus from  Edit-text?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything. please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below for all your `edittext` on click of `button`

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove the focus:

```
editText.clearFocus();
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

and this to hide the soft keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: But the problem is we cannot modify the old text

Answer (score 0):

In the xml you should use these

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

And in the java class use the OnTouch listener for the visible of curson on click on edit text

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.email_et:

            EDIT_TEXT.setCursorVisible(true);


        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```